# For loop for Arrays - Adding from previous value

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, numbers

I have the following code from Programming with c from Koshar. I did understand how it works, i just don't get where in the for loop will grab the previous value. The expected result I pasted it under the code for organization purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int number [10] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i, j;

    for( j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
            number[j] += number[i];

    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        printf ("%i ", number [j]);

        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

> 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256

Comment: This line: number[j] += number[i]; is actually a shortcut method for writing this line: number[j] = number[j] + number[i];  That is where the current number is being updated from prior numbers.

Comment: BTW: using the '{' and '}' around every code block, even single line code blocks, greatly increases readability and makes the chance of a later maintainer of the code much less likely to make an error in editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's going on you should print the state of the array `number` after each iteration of the outer `for` loop (i.e. the loop on `j`). Here is how the array would look:

```
Before:       1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
After 1 run:  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
After 2 runs: 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
After 3 runs: 1 1 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
After 4 runs: 1 1 2 4 8 0 0 0 0 0 
After 5 runs: 1 1 2 4 8 16 0 0 0 0 
After 6 runs: 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 0 0 0 
After 7 runs: 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 0 0 
After 8 runs: 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 0 
After 9 runs: 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
```

The inner `for` loop (on `i`) adds all previous numbers collected so far into the number in position `j`, so `numbers[1]` has a sum of items 0..0, `numbers[2]` has a sum of items 0..1, `numbers[3]` has 0..2, and so on. You can see how each iteration replaces the next zero with an appropriate sum of numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, how do I "print the state"? I didn't know that I could print like you did. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MyNameIsHaruo I took the printing logic from your code, and added it to the outer loop. I needed to rename the loop variable from `j` to `k`, and put curly braces around the code inside the outer loop, because now we have multiple statements inside.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I did understand how it works, i just don't get where in the for loop will grab the previous value.

This block of code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
        number[j] += number[i];
```

puts the sum of all the values of the elements up to index `n` in the element with index `n+1`

It so happens that

```
1 + 1 = 2 => Twice the last value.
1 + 1 + 2 = 4 => Twice the last value.
1 + 1 + 2 +  ... + n = 2*n => Twice the last value.
```

Comment: Thanks! This made me understand better what @dasblinkenlight commented =)

Answer (score -2):

for( j = 0; j < 10; ++j) this is your outer loop
for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) this is your inner loop

step 1.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=0 so do not run).and number[0]=1
 step 2.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=1 so do not run).and number[1]=1
 step 3.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=2 so do not run).and number[2]=2
 step 4.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=3 so do not run).and number[3]=4
 step 5.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=4 so do not run).and number[4]=8
 step 6.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=5 so do not run).and number[5]=16
 step 7.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=6 so do not run).and number[6]=32
 step 8.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=7 so do not run).and number[7]=64
 step 8.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=8 so do not run).and number[8]=128
 step 10.your outer loop run one time and inner loop run for j time.(as j=9 so do not run).and number[9]=256

Comment: Could you format your answer to make it easier on the eyes? You've also mistyped step 9 (it's 8 right now).

Comment: please, if you want to be accepted just do a right format to your answer.